PostgreSQL: Usar id de la tabla que contiene el trigger en un procedimiento almacenado
Tengo una tabla la cual tiene un campo retentionTime que debe actualizarse de acuerdo a otra tabla por medio de un procedimiento almacenado, necesito que en el procedimiento pueda enviar el id de la primera tabla para hacer subquerys correspondientes y se haga el calculo, intente con el new y old y me devuelve null por lo que no se hace el calculo.
El procedimiento esta asignado a la tabla archivo_gestion que tiene los campos id y retentionTime, en definitiva necesito enviar el id de archivo_gestion al procedimiento o alguna forma de usarlo ahi dentro para cada fila, muchas gracias
Tabla archivo gestion
archivo_gestion(
       id int,
       retentionTime Date //Es el campo que se debe actualizar con el insert 
)

Procedimiento que se dispara al hacer la inserción
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.updatetime()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
DECLARE
    id int4;
BEGIN

new."retentionTime" = CURRENT_DATE +(
    SELECT
        "tiempoAlmacenamiento"
    FROM
        tabla_retencion
    LEFT JOIN serie ON tabla_retencion.id = serie."tablaRetencionId"
WHERE
    serie.id IS NOT NULL
    AND serie.id =(
        SELECT
            serie.id
        FROM
            serie
        WHERE
            "archivoGestionId" =(new."id"))
        AND "tipoArchivo" = 'AG')::numeric * '1 year'::interval;

RETURN NEW;

END;

$function$

Esta es la tabla de retención, aquí indico el id y los tiempos que deberá guardar el registro


Código como texto por favor.

Hola, por favor ya edite la pregunta

Estas confundiendo un procedimiento almacenado con un trigger??? los procedimientos no tiene new u old...

@gbianchi, Vale muchas gracias, el caso es que se dispara al insertar un registro en esa tabla

ok.. tenes un trigger en una tabla.. new y old apuntan a esa tabla, no a otra.. me tenes confundido...

@gbianchi, si el new.retentionTime y el new.id  esta apuntando a la tabla archivo gestion, ahora para sacar el tiempo de retentionTime debo hacer subquerys en otras tablas, estoy revisando y las subconsultas estan bien pero en la ultima parte donde pongo el new.id me regresa NULO porque aun no se ha hecho el insert en la tabla archivo_gestion, entonces nose porque no me esta funcionando el triigger si claramente lo tengo para AFTER INSERT

create trigger setTimeToAg AFTER INSERT on archivo_gestion for EACH ROW EXECUTE procedure updatetime();
